# Is Exchange Online cmdlet Update-DistributionGroupMember transactional/atomic?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

There is an Exchange Online/Exchange 2016 Powershell Cmdlet **Update-DistributionGroupMember** which is supposed to *...replace all members of distribution groups...* (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335049(v=exchg.160).aspx).  Does anyone know if I can trust it to be atomic/transactional, meaning that it will either complete its task or give me an error and leave the distribution group membership as it was?  Or do I have to be prepared for the scenario in which it only does part of its task and leaves the DG in a halfway state?

thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 0):

This cmdlet notwithstanding. The same can be said for any code you run. Out of box or self created.

You must always be prepared for failure. Just like the old adage, the only good backup up is a tested and validated one. The number of times, I've seen org do backups and never test the restore and then realize that backup was crap, I've stopped counting.

Trust is on the process, validations in that process, and intimate knowledge of the actions about to be taken, not the code alone.

Bulk updates, like this, are always an one an done thing. It either works or it doesn't. Which is why they should always be approached with caution, to avoid corruption. Otherwise, you need to chunk the update and validate success of a chunk before you attempt to process another chunk.

There is no out of box concept of apply a change, validate the change before moving to the next without you writing that logic in to you code.

PowerShell does have the concept of transactions, but not all things support it.

```
# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Start-Transaction).Parameters
Get-help -Name Start-Transaction -Examples
Get-help -Name Start-Transaction -Full
Get-help -Name Start-Transaction -Online
```

So, you have to manually look at each of the planned cmdlets and see if it supports the -UseTransaction option and if that meets your needs. You can do that this way...

```
Get-Help * -parameter UseTransaction
```

Comment: I agree that I always have to watch out for failure; I guess I'm trying to figure out what kinds of failures are possible with this particular cmdlet.

Per its documentation, this cmdlet does not support the `UseTransaction` parameter.

thanks!

Comment: No worries. using that last cmdlet that we grep all help files and find the parameter string, you'll see that there are a limited number that support that UseTransaction parameter.  Consider this an other cmdlets like it no different than running a bulk update on AD user properties. It's either going to write all settings passed in or it's not. So, my approach always is to run a getter first, run the setter and run the getter and compare. I've not seen any corruption happen with these on-prem / cloud, but errors based on what was piped in by me, then sure.